# Inverse of a Versor

Tags: geometric-algebras

Let $A=a_1a_2\ldots a_N$ be a versor, where $a_i$ is a vector for all $i$.  Let $A^\dagger$ denote the reversion of $A$.
Let $a_ia_j$ denote the geometric product of vectors $a_i$ and $a_j$.

According to the book on Geometric Algebra for Computer Games by John Vince, the following is true:

\begin{align}
  A^\dagger A &= (a_Na_{N-1}\ldots a_2a_1)(a_1a_2\ldots a_{N-1}a_N) \\
    &= ( a_N ( a_{N-1} \ldots ( a_2 ( a_1 a_1 ) a_2 ) \ldots a_{N-1} ) a_N ) \\
    &= |a_1|^2 ( a_N ( a_{N-1} \ldots ( a_2 a_2 ) \ldots a_{N-1} ) a_N ) \\
    &= |a_1|^2 + |a_2|^2 + \cdots |a_N|^2.
\end{align}

Here, I get confused.  I think that $a_2 a_2=|a_2|^2$, which is a scalar.  Therefore,  I would have guessed that $A^\dagger A = |a_1|^2 |a_2|^2 \cdots |a_N|^2$.  Why do the scalars get added versus multiplied?

I've included an image of the relevant portion fo the page here:
[image: Excerpt from text]

Comment: You should add definitions to your question. What is a versor? Just a finite sequence of vectors? To which vector space do they belong? What is the geometric product? Scalar product? And how are versors multiplied?

Comment: @PaulFrost These are all standard definitions in the geometric algebra. I’m just a beginner, but it looks like a neat subject!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a typo.  Consider the simplest example $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $A = \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2$

$$A^\dagger A = \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 = 1 \ne 2.$$

Some additional confirmation can be had by looking at the product of a wedge with its reverse.  For a wedge of two vectors $A = \mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y}$, we have the following fairly well known identity:
$$\begin{aligned}\left\langle{{A^\dagger A}}\right\rangle&= \left\langle{{(\mathbf{y} \wedge \mathbf{x})(\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y})}}\right\rangle \\ &= \mathbf{y} \cdot \left( { \mathbf{x} \cdot (\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y})} \right) \\ &= \mathbf{y}^2 \mathbf{x}^2 - \left( {\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}} \right)^2.\end{aligned}$$

Since a versor (ref: Geometric Algebra for Computer Science) is a product of vectors, if the wedged vectors above are perpendicular, then $\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} \mathbf{y}$ and we are left with

$$\begin{aligned}\left\langle{{A^\dagger A}}\right\rangle&= \left\langle{{(\mathbf{y} \mathbf{x})(\mathbf{x} \mathbf{y})}}\right\rangle \\ &=  \mathbf{y}^2 \mathbf{x}^2,\end{aligned}$$

which is also a product of squared magnitudes, and not their sum.

Comment: The definition of versor that I know is simply any product of (unit?) vectors; they needn't be perpendicular in general. Otherwise, in 2D, we could only do reflections and $180^\circ$ rotations.

Comment: @mr_e_man.  Thanks.  I don't use that term, and clearly guessed wrong what it meant.  I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PeeterJoot I just purchased your book last week!  Thank you so much for your answer.  :)

Comment: @NicNic8 I've uploaded a new pdf today with a few error fixes: http://peeterjoot.com/writing/geometric-algebra-for-electrical-engineers/